# i am trying for a function for excel which is to sum up excel's data sheet

Tags: excel, function, grouping

```
id\date | 1 |  2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7
111     | q |  a  | q  | a  | a  | a  | a
112     | a |  q  | q  | q  | a  | q  | a
113     | w |  w  | a  | w  | w  | a  | a
114     | w |  a  | q  | q  | w  | w  | w
115     | a |  a  | a  | a  | a  | w  | a
```

this is an example of the table i have in  excel sheet and i want the following output in another sheet, in the output sheet we ignore "a"

```
id   | code |  start_date   |  end_date   |  total
111  |  q   |  01-01-2013   | 01-01-2013  |     1
111  |  q   |  03-01-2013   | 03-01-2013  |     1
112  |  q   |  02-01-2013   | 04-01-2013  |     3
112  |  q   |  06-01-2013   | 06-01-2013  |     1
113  |  w   |  01-01-2013   | 02-01-2013  |     2
113  |  w   |  04-01-2013   | 05-01-2013  |     2
114  |  w   |  01-01-2013   | 01-01-2013  |     1
114  |  q   |  03-01-2013   | 04-01-2013  |     2
114  |  w   |  05-01-2013   | 07-01-2013  |     3
115  |  w   |  06-01-2013   | 06-01-2013  |     1
```

like in the following output i want to create a excel sheet where in 'id' we get the employee id and the code i.e "q" or "w" in the code column and start date and end date. start date and end date depends on if the code is just on one date if so then the start date and end date remains the same but if the code is continuous for 2 or more days then the start date is when the event started and end date is when the even got over. and the total even if there is a single gap between two events of the same kind two entries have to be made like in employee 113. please check the output and if you can provide me with a function to accomplish the output, it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the module I have come up with. Not much of VBA coder, But did the best I could, Some hardcoding is done like Sheet name i have assumed to be "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", You can change those as per your need, and neater nested IF can be used:

```
            Sub test()
            Dim hold_last_value As String 'To hold the value of code of previous cell for a given id
            Dim counter As Integer 'To hold the value of days count for which a given event was held continuously for a given id
            Dim from_date As Variant 'To hold the start date of the event
            Dim to_date As Variant 'To hold the end date of an event
            Dim row_writer_index As Integer 'To hold the value of the row to which the next output is to be written, Is passed as a ByRef argument to the function
            Dim lastid As Integer 'To hold the last looped ID, In case the row changes without the event being stopped at the last date
            Dim last_row As Integer 'To generalize the code to parse any amounts of row
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            hold_last_value = 0
            counter = 0
            row_writer_index = 1
            last_row = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

             '' To loop the IDs
             For Each col_looper In Range("A2:A" & last_row)
              row_num = col_looper.Row
              'MsgBox (col_looper & row_num)
              '' To loop the events for each IDs
              For Each row_looper In Range("B" & row_num, "H" & row_num)
                'MsgBox (row_num & row_looper)
                row_looper.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(row_looper.Value)
                ''Condition for row changes without the event being stopped at the last date
                If (lastid <> col_looper.Value And counter <> 0) Then
                  Call writer(hold_last_value, lastid, from_date, to_date, counter, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"), row_writer_index)
                  counter = 0
                  from_date = Null
                  to_date = Null
                ElseIf (row_looper.Value <> "a" And counter = 0) Then
                  'MsgBox (col_looper & "--" & row_looper & "---" & row_num & "---" & hold_last_value & "---" & from_date & "---" & to_date & "---" & counter)
                  counter = 1
                  hold_last_value = row_looper.Value
                  from_date = Cells(1, row_looper.Column).Value
                  to_date = Cells(1, row_looper.Column)
                ElseIf (row_looper.Value = "a" And counter <> 0) Then
                  'MsgBox (col_looper & "--" & row_looper & "---" & row_num & "---" & hold_last_value & "---" & from_date & "---" & to_date & "---" & counter)
                  Call writer(hold_last_value, col_looper.Value, from_date, to_date, counter, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"), row_writer_index)
                  hold_last_value = ""
                  counter = 0
                  from_date = Null
                  to_date = Null
                ElseIf (row_looper.Value <> "a" And counter <> 0 And hold_last_value = row_looper.Value) Then
                  'MsgBox (col_looper & "--" & row_looper & "---" & row_num & "---" & hold_last_value & "---" & from_date & "---" & to_date & "---" & counter)
                  counter = counter + 1
                  to_date = Cells(1, row_looper.Column)
                ElseIf (row_looper.Value <> "a" And counter <> 0 And hold_last_value <> row_looper.Value) Then
                  'MsgBox (col_looper & "--" & row_looper & "---" & row_num & "---" & hold_last_value & "---" & from_date & "---" & to_date & "---" & counter)
                  Call writer(hold_last_value, col_looper.Value, from_date, to_date, counter, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2"), row_writer_index)
                  hold_last_value = row_looper.Value
                  counter = 1
                  from_date = Cells(1, row_looper.Column).Value
                  to_date = Cells(1, row_looper.Column).Value
                Else
                End If
                lastid = col_looper.Value
              Next row_looper
             Next col_looper

            End Sub
            '' WRITER FUNCTION
            Private Function writer(ByVal code As String, ByVal id As Integer, ByVal from_date As Variant, ByVal to_date As Variant, ByVal total As Integer, ByVal sheet_name As Worksheet, ByRef row_writer_index As Integer)
              Dim ws As Worksheet
              Dim x As Integer
              Dim a As Integer
              Set ws = sheet_name
              a = id
              ws.Activate
              ws.Range("A" & row_writer_index) = id
              ws.Range("B" & row_writer_index) = code
              ws.Range("C" & row_writer_index) = from_date
              ws.Range("D" & row_writer_index) = to_date
              ws.Range("E" & row_writer_index) = total
              Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
              row_writer_index = row_writer_index + 1
              x = row_writer_index
            End Function
```